# The undertone of the phrase "никак не получится"

Tags: значения

> Я с радостью помогу. Только работать постоянно **никак не получится**.

I'm trying to grasp the undertone of this phrase. Does it mean:

> Try as I might, working full-time just won't work out for me in any way.
>
> {or}: Regrettably, I won't be able to work full-time. I just can't make it happen, despite my best intentions to the contrary.
>
> {or}: I wish I could work full-time, but circumstances don't allow me to.

I mean, rather than showing a strong refusal on the part of the speaker:

> I'd be glad to help, but there's no way I'm going to work full-time.

---

On another note: Can I use "получиться" and "удаться" interchangeably here, or are the two somehow nuanced in this specific sentence?

> Я с радостью помогу. Только работать постоянно **никак не удастся**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я с радостью помогу. Только работать постоянно никак не удастся /не получится.

My feeling is the following. Both verbs are interchangeable in this situation. It means he will help /he is eager to help, but due to some circumstances he can't work full time. And it doesn't depend on him.

Comment: So can I use these expressions as a mild refusal?

Comment: Could you give a situation? You know that everything depends on the context. Боюсь,  у меня не получится is OK in many situations, but it's better to know what you mean.

Comment: "Regrettably, I won't be able to work full time." Hi. This is what I had in mind.

Comment: Yes, it's OK, you can say it.

Answer (score 1):

"I'll gladly help. But working full time just isn't possible for me." It's like the second or third option. It's saying it can't happen, without going into specifics, a polite refusal.